# How to run skipped/Not Run test cases using TesNG

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I am using Selenium WebDriver with `TestNG` framework and I have around 300 test cases in my test suite. In some of the cases my suite will stop in the middle because of some sync issues. Is there any way in `TestNG` I can execute the skipped test cases again after completion of execution?

For an example:- out of 300 test cases 100 got executed successfully and 200 got skipped/Not Run. I need to execute these "skipped/Not Run" test cases automatically once my execution completes for the first time.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question before and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803691/how-to-optimize-testng-and-seleniums-tests). It is possible but requires a little careful work. Several ways are mentioned there. You need to see the code not easy to explain without the code

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to achieve this goal:

- Use the [RetryAnalyzer](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IRetryAnalyzer.html) to rerun the test direct after the execute
- TestNG creates the file [testng-failed.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning) with all failed test case. You can start TestNG with only this tests.